# Cannot read property '$route' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, quasar-framework

I'm trying to access $route outside of the export default section, but it's undefined. It's accessible anywhere in the export default and the template section though. How can we access $route.name outside of the export default section?

```
import { useMeta } from "quasar";

const metaData = {
  title: this.$route.name,  // <---- HERE
  titleTemplate: (title) => `${title}`,
};

export default {
  setup() {
   useMeta(metaData);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare your `metaData` object inside a watcher for `$route()` hook and stop using `setup()` altogether.

```js
import { useMeta } from "quasar";

export default {
  watch: {
    $route () {
      const metaData = {
        title: this.$route.name,
        titleTemplate: (title) => `${title}`,
      }
      useMeta(metaData);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems not working either in the setup section. But it can work in data(), methods, computed, watchers, and any lifcycle hooks. Is there something I miss?

Comment: Oh `setup()` isnt a standard Vue hook, why are you using it? Can you use `created()` instead?

Comment: I'm using the metaData to set the title bar to the page name which is declared in the routes. I put the declaration on the parent page (acting as the base layout of the entire app) so that the code will not be repetitive on other pages. If I use created, the title bar will not be updated until after I reload the page. I was thinking to make the most out of mixins instead to get around it. But the problem arises, I have to import my mixins to every single page that I've built and it might lead to other problems for other developers in the future if they want to develop the app I'm constructing.

Comment: Could you `watch` for changes on `$route` and then call `useMeta` in the watcher? That way it'll update for every route change. I'll update my answer

Comment: It works when the base path is different. But when it's routing from one child of path to another child of path, it doesn't work. I watch $route(to, from) {...}. Is that correct?

Comment: Is the watcher not firing on child route changes or is the route name just the same?

Comment: Sorry. It's working now. My npm development acts weirdly sometimes. Thanks a lot for your help. Watchers can solve the problem.